# What is it about my julia function that is incomplete?

Tags: julia

I am writing a function, actually translating it from a pseudocode form to julia. I keep getting the following complaint:

julia> include("coefficients.jl")
ERROR: syntax: incomplete: "function" at /Users/comerduncan/MarkFiniteDiffDerivativs/coefficients.jl:1 requires end
 in include at boot.jl:244
while loading /Users/comerduncan/MarkFiniteDiffDerivativs/coefficients.jl, in expression starting on line 1

Here is my current version of the function:

```
function coefficients(order, x_list, x0)
    M = order
    N = length(x_list) - 1
delta = [0 for i=0:N,j=0:N,k=0:M]
delta[0,0,0]= 1
c1 = 1
for n =1:N+1
    c2 = 1
        for nu =0:n
            c3 = x_list[n]-x_list[nu]
            c2 = c2 * c3
            if n <= M
        delta[n,n-1,nu]=0
            for k=0:min(n,M)+1
                delta[k,n,nu] = (x_list[n]-x0)*delta[k,n-1,nu] -\
                k*delta[k-1,n-1,nu]
                delta[k,n,nu] /= c3
    end # k

    end # nu

        for m=0:min(n,M)+1
            delta[m,n,n] = c1/c2*(m*delta[m-1,n-1,n-1] \
            - (x_list[n-1]-x0)*delta[m,n-1,n-1] )
    end # m
        c1 = c2
end # n

return delta

end
```

Comment: It does not seem that the pasting of my function preserved the indentions. Please note that all "end"s of for loops are at the same indention level as the for at the head of the loop. Sorry if that is confusing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unless I'm missing something, you have four `end`s, and four loops: but you also write `if n <= M`, and that isn't ended.

So your `end # nu` isn't actually closing the `nu` loop, it's closing the `if`, and you have one too few.

Comment: Thanks!  My error was not remembering julia is not python in many ways.